# Overflow-y not working on iPad

Tags: ios, css, ipad, overflow

I have a panel with a scrollable content. It works fine in every browser & device except for iPad (no matter what browser I use on the iPad).

I have a panel-container and a panel-slide

```
.panel-container {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
}

.panel-slide {
    width:90%;
    height: 90%;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: white;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The panel-slide contains a lot of content, so I get the scroll bar. However I can't scroll on iPad.

I have googled the problem and have tried the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch, but I can't seem to get to the bottom of it.

What is there to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be helpful, but I had a similar issue, and this is how I resolved it.

### My issue:

My page has a popup element that gets populated by AJAX with a list of clickable links. When this element is pre-populated with the rest of the page (some pages required the list to be visible from initial page load), it worked fine. But, when I opened the element and populated the list, as mentioned above, using AJAX, the list would not scroll on iOS.

### The problem, as far as I could tell:

In the interim between clicking the button to open the list and when the server responded with the populated list, I had the element show some simple text saying "Loading...". I found that when this was removed, and the element was already populated from the page load, it would work fine. It seemed that as long as there were already contents in the list with a height greater than the containing element, it would be scroll-able when the list populated.

### My resolution:

What I did was to take the simple text in the interim from "Loading..." and to wrap it in a div that would prompt scrolling, like such: "`<div style='height:1000px;'>Loading...</div>`", and that seemed to work for me.

Again, I hope that this can help someone, or if not then perhaps someone with a little more skill than myself may be able to tell us why this might have worked.

Comment: I have the same issue, and I have set a min-height for my element so that it is scrollable from the first moment, but still it is not working on ipad and also any other mobile!

Answer (score -1):

There are no scrollbars in any of the iPhone OS. Use 2 fingers to scroll. They use gestures and not mouse scrolls so you are unable to achieve this without hacks.

It maybe worth looking at http://iscrolljs.com/

Comment: The problem is that I can't scroll with 2 fingers either.